# R: How to aggregate occurrences in df according to multiple column values/characters?

Tags: r, aggregate

I want to aggregate occurrences according to their "cell-names" (or values) in to different columns and the values should be summed up. This should be done for the example data below for the a1 and a2 cell characters in the first and second column. Therefore `a1` and `a2` should get a new name `A` and the `values` should be summed up in the 3rd column. However, the occurences should only be aggregated if the `product` is the same (4th column). If possible also by a second variable as year (which is not within the example). Here, example data:

```
df <- data.frame(from=c("a1", "a2", "C", "C", "D", "a1"),
                 to=c("B", "B", "a1", "a2", "B", "D"),
                 values=sample(1:10,6))
> df
  from to values product
1   a1  B      6       x
2   a2  B      2       x
3    C a1     10       y
4    C a2      2       z
5    D  B      6       w
6   a1  D      3       w
```

The result should look like this:

```
> res
  from to values product
1    A  B      8       x
2    C  A     10       y
3    C  A      2       z
4    D  B      6       w
5    A  D      3       w
```

Note that row 1 and 2 are combined to A (in [,1]) and values are summed up. While the 3rd, 4th row are only remaned to A (in [,2]), but not combined as the product character is different (in [,4])

Any suggestions how to solve this problem? Thanks for your ideas

Comment: Please be more specific, what are the criteria you want to use to merge the from values? Just by starting letter e.g. `res$from <- substr(df$from,1,1)`.

Comment: criteria is: levels `a1` and `a2` shold be agregated if `product`is the same. I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(from = toupper(substr(from, 1, 1)), 
           to = toupper(substr(to, 1, 1)), product) %>%
  summarise(values = sum(values))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
#Groups: from, to [?]
#
#   from    to product values
#  (chr) (chr)  (fctr)  (int)
#1     A     B       x      8
#2     A     D       w      3
#3     C     A       y     10
#4     C     A       z      2
#5     D     B       w      6
```

Comment: How can I get the results without the Source:/Groups: and (chr).. lines? So, the same structure as in object `res` in the question.

Comment: @N.Varela `dplyr` wraps data frames in a `tbl_df` class. These objects are structured in *exactly* the same way as regular data frames, but their behaviour has been tweaked a little to make them easier to work with. That being said, if for any reason you want to remove the `tbl_df` class, simply add `%>% data.frame` at the end of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(from=c("a1", "a2", "C", "C", "D", "a1"),
             to=c("B", "B", "a1", "a2", "B", "D"),
             values=c(6,2,10,2,6,3),product = c("x","x","y","z","w","w"))
df$from<-gsub("[[:digit:]]+$", "",as.character(df$from))
df$to<-gsub("[[:digit:]]+$", "",as.character(df$to))
df$from<-toupper(df$from)
df$to<-toupper(df$to)
df<-aggregate(df$values,list(from=df$from,to=df$to,product=df$product),FUN=sum)
```

Comment: If order of result is not importent, you can use this